# How to fix cursor lag in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I set the `editor.cursorSmoothCaretAnimation` to `true` in Visual Studio Code but the cursor lags behind when I type/select/delete text quickly:

[image]

I turned off all the extensions in VS Code by running `code --disable-extensions` in terminal but the problem persists.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: I just enabled it and for me it lags about 0.5 character

Comment: Maybe this lag depends on what kind of computer is used because mine is not very good. A cheap laptop running Ryzen 5 3500U with 8 Gigs of RAM. What is your computer's configuration?

Comment: It runs fine for me. Although it is quite annoying to have it enabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### I Found a Solution

tl;dr: I had set `editor.smoothScrolling` to `true`. Disabling that option (mostly) solved the issue:

[image]

The cursor does not stutter as much in person as it might look like it does in this gif. There is still a little bit of lag - about 1 to 1.5 characters, but not more than that. This is actually the same amount of lag I was seeing when every extension was disabled and all settings except `editor.cursorSmoothCaretAnimation` were commented out, which tells me that the lag can't be reduced any further (or at least I can't reduce it any further).

#### So how did I arrive at this solution?

Initially, I had disabled extensions temporarily by running `code --disable-extensions` in terminal but that didn't seem to solve the problem. So, I went ahead and manually disabled each extension (globally) and also commented out all my settings in the `settings.json` file, except `editor.cursorSmoothCaretAnimation`. Thankfully, I found that the cursor lag had reduced to about 1 to 1.5 characters. As disabling all the extensions had not solved the issue before, I had an inkling that my settings were to blame for the lag. Thus, I began going through each setting and began uncommenting them, one by one, and checking to see if the lag had returned. Finally, I found that uncommenting the `editor.smoothScrolling` setting reintroduced the bothersome lag. Hoping that that setting was the only one causing it, I uncommented all of the other settings and enabled all my extensions. To my surprise, the lag did not increase any further. Later on, I did a few checks and I can confirm that `editor.smoothScrolling` is the setting to blame for this.

#### Why?

Why this happens, I do not know. I will be opening a new [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109787) about it in the VS Code Github.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling **Save Typing** extension has solved the issue in my case.

[image: Example]

Comment: I have not installed that extension in VS Code